# prove that $a_n \ge (n + 2016)^2$ for some $n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A infinite sequence $\{ a_n \}_{n \ge 0}$ of real numbers satisfy $a_n \ge n^2$. Suppose that for each $i, j \ge 0$ there exist $k, l$ with $(i,j) \neq (k,l)$, $l - k = j - i$, and $a_l - a_k = a_j - a_i$. Prove that $a_n \ge (n + 2016)^2$ for some $n$.

Comment: Where did you find this?  It feels like a competition problem, so the source will give a clue to the level of solution expected.  What have you tried?

Comment: Arguing by contradiction seems to work here.

Comment: This is a competition problem. It is problem 7 from [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c312308_2016_korea_summer_program_practice_test).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose not, so $a_n<(n+2016)^2$ for all $n\geq 0$.

Plugging in $i=0$ and using $a_0\geq 0$, we know that for each $j$ there exists $k\geq 1$ such that
$$a_{j+k}\leq a_j+a_k. \tag{*}$$
Applying the assumed bounds gives
$$(j+k)^2 < (j+2016)^2 + (k+2016)^2$$
i.e.
$$(2j+k+2016)(k-2016) < (k+2016)^2$$
which for sufficiently large $j$ implies $k\leq 2016$. In particular if we define $M=\max_{1\leq n\leq 2016}(a_n/n)$ then
$$a_{j+k} \leq a_j + k M.$$
Using this repeatedly we get numbers $1\leq k_1,\dots,k_n\leq 2016$ with sum $K$ such that
$$a_{j+K} \leq a_j + KM$$
which is less than $(j+K)^2$ for large enough $K$, contradicting the hypothesis $a_n\geq n^2$.